# How to find duplicates in the array for xor method? algorithm complexity O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, xor

How to find duplicates in the array. In the case of the inverse problem when you have to find a unique element of all is clear you just xor all the elements and as a result we obtain a unique element.For example

```
int a[] = {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 16, 16};
int res = a[0];
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    res ^= a[i];
```

for example given an array

```
int a[] = {2, 4, 7, 8, 4, 5};
```

Here a duplicate is 4, but it is not clear how to find a duplicate element of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing the [Element Distinctness Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

Without extra space (and hashing) there is no `O(n)` solution to element distinctness problem, so you cannot modify the "xor algorithm for duplicate" for this problem.

The solutions for this problem are:

1. sort and iterate the sorted array to find dupes (easy in sorted array). This is `O(nlogn)` time.
2. Build a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the data (hash-based) and iterate the histogram when done to verify if all elements have value of 1 in the histogram - `O(n)` *average* case, O(n) space.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the duplicates in an array in 0(n) time by using the following algorithm.

```
  traverse the list for i= 0 to n-1 elements
  {
//check for sign of A[abs(A[i])] ;
 if positive then
 make it negative by   A[abs(A[i])]=-A[abs(A[i])];
 else  // i.e., A[abs(A[i])] is negative
  this   element (ith element of list) is a repetition
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This mutates the array.

Answer (score -1):

One solution can be to build a Hashset. It goes as follows-

```
 1. Initialize an empty hashset.
 2. For each element in array,
     a. Check if it is present in the hashset.
        If yes, you found the duplicate
        If not, add it to the hashset.
```

This way you can find all the duplicates in the array.

Space complexity: O(n) ; Time complexity: O(n)